# How to validate equivalency between two zip packages

Tags: linux, unix, command-line

I'm trying to validate if two zip packages are equivalent. I can not rely on md5sum. When I extract the two packages, and do a md5sum `diff` between all the files in the packages, there is no difference, and all files have equivalent md5sums. But the zip packages themselves have different md5sum values. My question is: How can I validate that two zip packages are equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

When you list the archive's content with

```
unzip -v archive.zip
```

you get a list of files with these column headings

> Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name

Depending on what you consider equivalent (e.g. Size, CRC, Name), you can extract the relevant columns for both archives, sort them and do a diff over the output.

Answer (score 0):

without unzipping the file you can use [zipinfo](http://www.info-zip.org/mans/zipinfo.html)

e.g:

`ipinfo 5.zip
Archive:  5.zip   158 bytes   1 file
drwxr-xr-x  3.0 unx        0 bx stor 18-Nov-13 07:23 501/
1 file, 0 bytes uncompressed, 0 bytes compressed:  0.0%`